# How can I collect heap memory distribution by types and memory ownership topology from a C++ application core dump?

Tags: c++, coredump, heap-profiling

I am trying different approaches to profiling the heap of a C++ application.

Lets say I have a process running in a production environment. I notice high memory consumption and take a full memory dump of it.

What I would like to do with this dump is to traverse it from thread stacks along the pointers and collect type statistics and memory ownership topology and distribution. If there was a tool that could do this it should have had understanding of smart pointers and container-like types to properly traverse memory and interpret the data. This would require some adaptor framework for the basic utility libraries used by my application (be they boost, stl or something else).

I tried tools like valgring-massif and tcmalloc+gperftools. They allow to inspect the call stacks which led to the memory allocations.

I would like to see the picture from the different angle. I want to see how much memory is allocated for each type and how ownership topology of my application looks like.

So my question is, are there any analysis tools which implement desribed approach?

Comment: You cannot, a heap is just a datastructure to administer memory allocation. It by itself does not contain ANY information on what types are stored there. It also looks like you are trying to analyze something after the fact. You could use a profiler to figure out which calls are being handled (excesively often). But knowing about what could allocate memory should be part of your desgin... or are you telling us the design is missing?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I understand what you mean but my idea is different.

Any memory that is not leaked is reachable from variables on the thread stack. My idea is to traverse the pointer references starting from the stack variables.

Comment: @user7860670 Memory profiler in Visual Studio relies on ETW and collects data over time rather than taking a memory snapshot which means it uses the same approach as Valgrind and gperftools I mentioned above.

Comment: I have not found any implementations of the ides so I decided to write some proof of concept with GDB Python API. Hopefully I will return with results.